# How sound generally works in computer and what tools do i have?

Tags: alsa

I am searching google for how sound works in linux for couple of days and still couldn't find a fine and basic article or tutorial.
What i am actually looking for is what termonologies do exist and what tools (terminal tools to create bash scripts) can i use to configure sound. I looking for something like:

- what is sound card?
- what is channel?
- what tools do i have?
- what modification can do to output sound?
- ...

Answer (score 2):

A sound card is a card (sometimes little more than a chip) for receiving and sending signals from/to audio jacks or other input standards for connecting audio input and output devices to a computer, integrated soundcards use the CPU to process the signals from input before forwarding them to whichever software is recording them, and also to process the sound outputs of the computer before forwarding them to the speakers.

A dedicated soundcard will usually have it's own dedicated sound processing unit and does not have to depend on the CPU.

A channel, at least in linux sound drivers is a word for a specific speaker you are targeting (for example 5.1 speakers have 6 channels, 1 for each speaker and 1 for the subwoofer, to understand this, lets say you have a 5.1 speaker setup, use the command **speaker-test -c6 -t wav** and it will read up for you all your speakers outputing sound to their individual channels one at a time) you pretty much don't need to know much about this unless you are configuring anything more than stereo or 2.1 speakers by hand.

What tools you have depends significantly on the distro, you tagged alsa, so alsa's tools (if you have them installed, if you don't there is bound to be a package in one of your distributions software repositories with them) you will have access to commands such as **amixer**, **aplay**, **speaker-test** and **alsamixer** (these are honestly the only ones I ever use) you may also have a graphical sound mixer, but that differs greatly between desktop environments and distributions. Things also get a lot more complicated if you are also using pulseaudio. Pulseaudio always runs on top of kernel sound drivers like alsa, it can not work on its own.

There are alternatives to alsa (primarily OSS/Open Sound Software) I won't go int any sort of details about that.

There are three primary files for configuring alsa. There is a system-wide alsa configuration file, typically **/etc/asound.conf**, a per-user installation file located in the home directory of each user as **~/.asoundrc** (these files tend not to exist by default, although asound.conf may exist for the sole purpose of redirecting alsa to use pulseaudio if you are using pulseaudio) the third file would be kernel modprobe files, typically in **/etc/modprobe.d/** it can be named anything you want, alsa.conf is what I typically use. Here you can do the important task of blacklisting audio drivers for devices you have installed but do not intend on using (it is good to eliminate such drivers to minimize the odds of bugs in the default device selection process among other things), and setting the order in which alsa is meant to read your sound devices with a command called index (index=0 is going to be the default device, index=1 is going to be ordered after that, etc) it can also occasionally be used to enable options for these sound devices that are required for them to function proporly (common in laptops, especially ones that ship with funky 2.1 sound systems)

There is also a **usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf** file (or something similar) but I have not once used it.

The primary config file you will use to configure alsa is probably going to be your userbound **.asoundrc**, that is what users most commonly do.

As for what modifications you can do... you can go from applying an equalizer to upscaling sounds (so 2 channel sound will be output to all your speakers if you have more) and changing the default output device, you can also create new audio outputs using different configurations or a different sound device which you can then configure specific programs to use as needed (keep in mind one of pulseaudio's main goals is to automate most of this). The tool you are likely to use the most is going to be **alsamixer** (a command-line mixer to control your volume, it also supports configuring per-channel volume)

I use my asoundrc to do all these things, but if you have pulseaudio you are probably better off just using your given GUI configuration tools (such as pavucontrol) or uninstalling it completely if possible. Pulseaudio adds considerable latency to your sound (output and input) and can cause problems with some programs (most noticable for me was when I tried to use ffmpeg for screencasting)

Pulseaudio and OSS are both outside of my area of expertise, I use neither. A bigger question than "what modifications you can do" to the alsa drivers would be "what modifications you wish to make", there is usually a way to do it (roundabout or not), ALSA is very configurable. ALSA itself is a part of the kernel, it's a soundcard driver interface and compilation essentially, unless you have a distro that specifically wants to use something else than alsa, you have alsa, but if you have pulseaudio installed, you should not try to configure alsa directly (use pulseaudio to interface with it instead) you can easily find information about pulseaudio with a google search.

Also for future reference, I recommend seeking out [the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) when you are looking for answers like this, it is a well recognized source for information about all kinds of linux software.

One last thing of interest, there is this little function known as dmixing, I won't explain it in detail but what it does is allow you to output sound from more sources than one (i.e. you normally wouldn't be able to play two sounds at once in linux without this) this is enabled by default in pulseaudio for any and all devices, it's one of the reasons pulseaudio was made to begin with. But for alsa dmixing is only enabled by default for stereo devices, meaning that if you have a sound configuration that uses more than 2 channels you're going to have to apply dmixing manually, shoot me a comment if you want to know how to do this.

There is an alternative sound server software to pulseaudio known as JACK. It doesn't have the latency issues of pulseaudio, in case you were wondering. But I have never used it (I tend to just use pure alsa myself, it's what works best for me)

Your question was a bit broad, but I answered it as well as I could. Any questions?